# Debian start-stop-daemon. Java start jar File

Tags: java, service, jar, debian, start-stop-daemon

I have this command in a shellscript in /etc/init.d/

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/$NAME.pid --background --exec /usr/bin/java -jar /home/username/myjar.jar
```

If i execute this i get this error

```
start-stop-daemon: unable to stat /usr/bin/java -jar /home/username/myjar.jar (No such file or directory)
```

If i execute

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /home/username/myjar.jar
```

in the commandline everything is fine .. i don't get my mistake :(

Comment: `--chuid root` <-- why?

Comment: a result of my desperation .. is removed now

Comment: please repost your answer.. i noticed to late that you removed the " ' " .. your answer fixed my problem. i will accept it

Comment: Uh, undeleted, but what "'" are you talking about? And does it actually solve the problem?

Comment: OK again my mistake. In the time till your answer i changed something. I made " ' " around the exec statement. But nevertheless your answer fixed my problem

Comment: Good to know :) However, don't forget to `--chuid` to a "sane" user

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/$NAME.pid \
    --background \
    --exec /usr/bin/java -- -jar /home/username/myjar.jar
```

It seems like you need to separate the executable (here `/usr/bin/java` from its argument with `--`.

(oh, also change the uid to an appropriate user; `root` should not be required)

Comment: Thank your for the fast and nice responses.